# Добрый вечер. Проблема с setInterval. Функция вообще не выполняется

Tags: javascript, jquery

Объясните пожалуйста проблему и предложите решение или альтернативный вариант. Мне необходимо чтобы при вводе текста в textarea он дублировался в другой див.

```
         <textarea type="text" class="width1 div-button" id="div-html"></textarea> 
            <textarea type="text" class="width1 div-button" id="div-css"></textarea>
            <textarea type="text" class="width1 div-button" id="div-javascript"></textarea>
            <div type="text" class="width1 div-button" id="div-output"></div>
            

           setInterval(htmlOutput, 1000);

            function htmlOutput(){
        
            $("#div-output").html($("#div-html").value);
        
        }
```

Comment: также вместо $("#div-output").html пробовал .html не решило проблему

Comment: примерно так, только с верным синтаксисом обращения к элементам onChange="div2.value=this.value"?

Comment: Не пойму как это записать в коде, Владимир

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#div-html").keyup(function() {
  $("#div-output").html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type="text" class="width1 div-button" id="div-html"></textarea>
<textarea type="text" class="width1 div-button" id="div-css"></textarea>
<textarea type="text" class="width1 div-button" id="div-javascript"></textarea>
<div type="text" class="width1 div-button" id="div-output"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо решено!

Answer (score 0):

`$("#div-html")` - вернет `jQuery` объект.

Чтобы получить значение из jQuery объекта нужно использовать [**метод** `val`](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

```js
setInterval(htmlOutput, 1000);

function htmlOutput() {

  $("#div-output").html($("#div-html").val());

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type="text" class="width1 div-button" id="div-html"></textarea>
<textarea type="text" class="width1 div-button" id="div-css"></textarea>
<textarea type="text" class="width1 div-button" id="div-javascript"></textarea>
<div type="text" class="width1 div-button" id="div-output"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо решено!